# Add a column to one data frame based on multiple values in another by index number

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data-manipulation

I have two very large data frames. The first data frame has a list of county names and their associated fip codes. The second data set only has their fip codes.

I want to add two columns to the second data frame with their associated county names.

Suppose this is df1

```
df1 = data.frame(countyname = c("Archuleta County, CO","Baca County, CO","Cheyenne County, CO","Kiowa County, CO","Cimarron County, OK","Rio Arriba County, NM","Conejos County, CO"),
                 fipscounty = c(8007,8009,8017,8061,35039,40025,8021))

countyname fipscounty
1  Archuleta County, CO       8007
2       Baca County, CO       8009
3   Cheyenne County, CO       8017
4      Kiowa County, CO       8061
5   Cimarron County, OK      35039
6 Rio Arriba County, NM      40025
7    Conejos County, CO       8021
```

EDIT: And this is df2

```
df2 = data.frame(county1=c(8007,8007,8009,8017),
                 distance=c(4,3,2,1),
                 county2=c(35039,8021,40025,8061))
  county1 distance county2
1    8007        4   35039
2    8007        3    8021
3    8009        2   40025
4    8017        1    8061
```

EDIT: I want the end result to look like this:

```
            countyname fipscounty distance        countyneighbor fipscounty2
1 Archuleta County, CO       8007        4   Cimarron County, OK       35039
2 Archuleta County, CO       8007        3    Conejos County, CO        8021
3      Baca County, CO       8009        2 Rio Arriba County, NM       40025
4  Cheyenne County, CO       8017        1      Kiowa County, CO        8061
```

I want to transfer the county names from df1 to df2 using the fips codes from df1 and df2. Since they don't have the same column names, I'll likely have to do this using index number. But, I do not want to transfer the entire row, otherwise I'd have duplicate fips columns.

I tried this, but of course it errored

```
df2 <- left_join(df1,df2, by= df1[2])
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `match`.

```
m <- match(df2$county1, df1$fipscounty)
res <- cbind(df1[m, ], df1[match(df2$county2, df1$fipscounty), ])
names(res)[c(2, 4)] <- names(df2)[c(1, 3)]
res
#               countyname county1            countyname county2
# 1   Archuleta County, CO    8007   Cimarron County, OK   35039
# 1.1 Archuleta County, CO    8007    Conejos County, CO    8021
# 2        Baca County, CO    8009 Rio Arriba County, NM   40025
# 3    Cheyenne County, CO    8017      Kiowa County, CO    8061
```

### Edit

Based on your edit, you could include `merge` and `append` as tools.

```
m1 <- merge(df1a, df2a, by.x='fipscounty', by.y='county1')[c(2, 1, 3:4)]
append(m1, 
       list(countyneighbor=df1a[match(m1$county2, df1a$fipscounty), 
                                'countyname']), 3) |>
  as.data.frame()

#             countyname fipscounty distance        countyneighbor county2
# 1 Archuleta County, CO       8007        4   Cimarron County, OK   35039
# 2 Archuleta County, CO       8007        3    Conejos County, CO    8021
# 3      Baca County, CO       8009        2 Rio Arriba County, NM   40025
# 4  Cheyenne County, CO       8017        1      Kiowa County, CO    8061
```

**Note:**  R >= 4.1 used.

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(countyname = c("Archuleta County, CO", "Baca County, CO", 
"Cheyenne County, CO", "Kiowa County, CO", "Cimarron County, OK", 
"Rio Arriba County, NM", "Conejos County, CO"), fipscounty = c(8007, 
8009, 8017, 8061, 35039, 40025, 8021)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

df2 <- structure(list(county1 = c(8007, 8007, 8009, 8017), county2 = c(35039, 
8021, 40025, 8061)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

df1a <- structure(list(countyname = c("Archuleta County, CO", "Baca County, CO", 
"Cheyenne County, CO", "Kiowa County, CO", "Cimarron County, OK", 
"Rio Arriba County, NM", "Conejos County, CO"), fipscounty = c(8007, 
8009, 8017, 8061, 35039, 40025, 8021)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

df2a <- structure(list(county1 = c(8007, 8007, 8009, 8017), distance = c(4, 
3, 2, 1), county2 = c(35039, 8021, 40025, 8061)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response! This worked perfect on my fake df, but when I applied it to the real one, it gave a bunch of NAs. I'm almost certain this is because there are actually 3 columns in df2 (not 2). I omitted this third column in my original post. I updated my post to reflect this

Comment: @bandcar Can't replicate the `NA`s, just `names` are different, please try again.

Comment: I just tried it on the fake data, you're right, there are not any NAs, but it's missing the distance column. I'm trying to think of a way to show what's happening in my actual data frame as far as the NAs are concerned. Give me a few minutes!

Comment: @bandcar In this case you additionally could use `merge` and `append`, see edit.

Comment: I don't want to add too much information to this post, so I think I'll make a new post with my actual data. This works well with my fake data, but it gives me a bunch of NAs with the real set. I can't seem to reproduce it on the fake data. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @bandcar No hurry, get back to me as soon as you have a suitable example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244121/discussion-between-bandcar-and-jay-sf).